# ScriptProcessorNode internals

Tags: audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I have a question about the internal operation of the ScriptProcessorNode. During the onaudioprocess event is being handled by our javascript does the ScriptProcessorNode itself maintain some internal buffer to continue to capture and playback audio? If it has internal buffer space, how big? Also, can the onaudioprocess event be triggered by a user event?

Answer (score 1):

The audio system maintains these buffers, yes, because it has to asynchronously transfer the audio from the audio thread (and back).  It's not going to choke the main audio system processing, but if you don't respond quickly enough from the main thread onaudioprocess, it will glitch.

The buffers are... double-buffered, I think?  I can't remember, precisely.  The block size you pass in to the ScriptProcessorNode determines their size.

Finally, you CAN'T trigger an onaudioprocess by a user event (I mean, you could for testing purposes, I guess) - it's designed to be triggered when the audio system needs more data from the script processor node.

Comment: If it cannot be triggered by an user event, canyou send more data to it as they arrive. If one bufferful of data is not available when the onaudioprocess event happens, should we wait in the event processing for the data or just return without the data and wait for the next event.

Comment: Did some more testing. It looks like when the onaudioprocess event fires, you have to fill the buffer. The ScriptProcessorNode seems to fire at a fixed interval by the size of the buffer.